# Get rid of parts after the space in vector's string elements

Tags: r, string

I have a vector which consists of a list of strings, which are the combinations of first name and initials, I want to get rid of the initials

tried `sub()` and `strsplit()` but didn't work

```
name <- data.frame(c("Jones B", "Mike M", "Goods R.I"))

"Jones" "Mike" "Goods"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to match one or more space (`\\s+`) followed by characters (`.*`) and replace with blanks (`""`)

```
sub("\\s+.*", "", name[[1]])
#[1] "Jones" "Mike"  "Goods"
```

---

In case if we need compactness

```
library(stringr)
word(name[[1]], 1)
#[1] "Jones" "Mike"  "Goods"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want the word before the first space, you could also use the `stringi` package:

```
library(stringi)
stri_extract_first_words(c("Jones B", "Mike M", "Goods R.I"))
[1] "Jones" "Mike"  "Goods"
```